# find number in array divided into k parts

Tags: algorithms, sorting, efficiency

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to find the a number in an array with the following conditions:

> Array $A$ of size $n$ divided into even parts in the size of $k$
>
> - every element in each part is bigger than all the elements in the part
>     before (Lets say in the left)
> - every element in each part is smaller then then every elements in the part after it (lets say on the right)

At this moment after trying couple of ways I am under the impression that the only way is $O(n)$

Is it correct?

Comment: You can solve this in $O(\log(n/k) + k)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I managed to solve this in $O(log(n/k)+2k)$ Because as I understand there is no way to distinguish between two parts that are one near the other - lats say i know that my number is bigger then the first number in part $A$ and smaller than the first number in part $B$ I know for sure that my number is somewhere in parts $B$ or $A$ correct?  so where is my mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The complexity classes $O(\log(n/k)+k)$ and $O(\log(n/k)+2k)$ are identical.

Comment: I would call that $O(\log (n) + k)$ because  $O(\log(n/k)+k) =  O(log(n)-\log(k)+k)$ and $O(k-\log(k)) = O(k)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary representative from each part. Using binary search, you can find the two representatives which bracket the given element. You can then look for your given element in the $2k$ elements comprising the two parts that the representatives belong to. This algorithm takes time $O(\log(n/k) + k) = O(\log n + k)$, interpolating between the cases $k=1$ (sorted array, $O(\log n)$) and $k = n$ (unsorted array, $O(n)$).

Comment: Great that's exactly what I did, binary search + loop. But one more thing I am sorry for the ignorance but what is interpolation? (I am already tried to translate it)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "interpolating".  I meant it in a sense similar to [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).